# Should my mail server give a different server name?

Tags: exchange

Just noticed while checking mail headers. I can see first hope is a database server 10.90.2.117 to my exchange server 10.90.2.59. The name i see in a message header analyzer for my exchange server says the FQDN is UPPSRVEX4.upp-ltd.local and as the message leave our corporate firewall on IP 5.148.79.5 it still says FQDN is UPPSRVEX4.upp-ltd.local.

Is this OK/Correct or should it state something like mail.upp-ltd.com or mx.upp-ltd.com ? does the .local vs .com ending in FQDN matter?

[image: Message Header Analyzer header image]

Answer (score 3):

Depending on who you want to accept mail from your servers it is probably critical.

For example, to successfully email a gmail address, your server name in the HELO must have matching reverse DNS set up to the IP it is coming from - impossible with a `.local` or similar TLD.  You also need SPF and/or DKIM records, and using SMTP w/ SSL or TLS.  Of course the server name in the SSL/TLS cert needs to match the name in HELO, etc.

If this is simply for internal corporate communication, then the name doesn't matter much, but should probably have working DNS across your environment.  Personally, I'd just do it the right way....

Comment: So its actually only doing mail relaying for internal servers, but some of these services to email out to gmail, hotmail, yahoo etc.
We have a hybrid setup so our email flow goes from Clint server > Exchange > Firewall > Office 365 > Mimecast.
Do you know how that changes things?

Comment: Updated the send connector on our on-premise exchange 2016 server.

Set that to mail.upp-ltd.com as we have a DNS record that points to that external IP. I do need to work out reverse DNS with my ISP and DynDNS i think.

Do i need to update receive connectors as well? they only relay emails for internal servers and services.

Answer (score -1):

After an SMTP session is established, an SMTP protocol conversation starts between a sending e-mail server and a receiving e-mail server. The sending e-mail server or client sends the EHLO or HELO SMTP command and its FQDN to the receiving server. In response, the receiving server sends a success code and provides its own FQDN. You can customize the FQDN that's provided by the sending server if you configure this property on a Send connector, not receive connector.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4dde9b79-18e4-407f-8edc-896e6c40eb25/need-to-modify-server-response-to-ehlo-helo?forum=exchangesvradmin